# Inclusion gate as universal gate

Tags: digital-logic

Assuming that logic 0 is available, show that the INCLUSION gate is a
universal building block.

I don't know what inclusion gate is.

Comment: Join the club...

Answer (score 3):

Well, I've never heard of such a gate, however Newnes Dictionary of Electronics
 By S W Amos, Roger Amos) has.

[image]

Fine, but I also have no idea what an IF-THEN gate might be!

Fortunately, they do.

[image]

So, it's like a NAND gate with an inverter on input 2. You should be able to take it from there.